# Matlab lcm multiple variables check

Tags: matlab

I have the following code for my matlab function that is supposed to take the lcm of multiple numbers. I have the following:

```
function y = lcm1(x)
n = length(x);
if n < 2
   y = x; 
elseif n == 2
   y = lcm(x(1), x(2));
else
   y = lcm(x(1), x(2));
   for i = 3:n
      y = lcm(x(i) ,y);
   end 
end
```

However it won't seem to run but I can't find the error if anyone can see this? I am aware that this is painfully simple.

Thanks for any help

Comment: It works fine for me. What is it saved as? It must be saved as lcm1.m in a folder in the MATLAB path. How do you call it? Do you get any error messages? Any output at all? What is the output to screen if you write: `lcm1([3 4 5])`?

Comment: @RobertP. I get the following error:lcm1([3 4 5])
Undefined function 'lcm1' for input arguments of type 'double'

Comment: Have you saved it as `lcm1.m` in the MATLAB path? Either save it in the "Current folder", or add the folder to the working path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's nothing wrong with the function you have, although Luis' version is a slight improvement.

Follow the below instructions if you can't make it run:

1. Make sure the file has the same name as the function name, in this case `lcm1`. Note that the full path (if it's not too long) is shown in the top bar. It must end with `...\lcm1.m`.

[image]

2. Make sure the folder you save it in is in the MATLAB path. In my case this folder is "C:\Users\Robert\Documents\MATLAB". You can find the current folder here:

[image]

Note that I have a few folders that are grey in the MATLAB folder, (graphViz4Matlab). MATLAB can't find any files / functions inside these folders. By double clicking you will make it the current folder, and by right clicking on it you get several options including adding it to the MATLAB path. You probably want to add it to the path, which should make it appear black.

When the above is done, writing `lcm1(1:5)` in the command window in MATLAB should result in (as you can see in the second screenshot above:

```
lcm1(1:5)
ans =
    60
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code seems to work fine.

A slightly [neater](https://quotabl.es/quotes/50349) approach is to use recursion:

```
function y = lcm1(x)
n = length(x);
if n < 2 %// 0 or 1 elements: nothing to do
    y = x;
elseif n == 2 %// 2 elements: call lcm to do the actual work
    y = lcm(x(1), x(2));
else %// combine first two numbers with lcm, then call lcm1 again
    y = lcm1([lcm(x(1), x(2)) x(3:end)]);
end
```